# Google Chart Issue on Typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, google-visualization

I want to draw google chart with dynamic data on angular 4. i am using visual studio web express 2015. with static data its working fine. i am sending the data to angular by serializing the data table from web API. 
is there any other way to create google chart with dynamic values on typescript??

i want the result like this

```
public GoalSetProgress_ChartData = [['Status', 'Number of Employees'],['Goal set for the employees', 210],['Goals not set for the employees', 40]];
```

on console.log i can see the result as

```
[{"Status":"Goal Set Pending","NumberofEmployees":"20"},{"Status":"Goal Set Completed","NumberofEmployees":"15"}]
```

the chart is not drawn and showing error  this format.

Comment: this may not help but there is a json format you can use for a google data table [found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), if you can't get array needed, maybe you can reformat the json version...